# How to pipe installed packages to apt-cache?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude, pipe

I'm trying to get package description of my installed packages.

It would look like this:

```
sudo apt list --installed | sed 's/\/.*//' | apt-cache search {} \;
```

The problem is to send each line from sed to apt-cache.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: @steeldriver no, `search`, something short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{} \;` syntax that you have guessed is specific to the `find` command and won't work in this context. You *could* use `xargs` ex.

```
apt list --installed | sed 's/\/.*//' | xargs -n1 apt-cache search
```

Actually `xargs` has its own `{}`-like syntax that you could use here, i.e.

```
. . . | xargs -n1 -I{} apt-cache search {}
```

although it is redundant in this case (it's useful for cases where you want to substitute the piped value at a point other than the end of the command).

---

However the `apt-cache search` command is almost certainly not what you want here - it will search the entire (online) catalog for packages that match each of the results of `apt list --installed`. Even if you restrict the scope of the search using `--names-only` you will still get many false positives (i.e. substring matches between packages that ARE installed and packages that AREN'T). It will also be horribly inefficient.

For this particular task I'd skip `apt` altogether and use the lower-level `dpkg-query` command ex.

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}: ${binary:Summary}\n'
```

which will be **much** more efficient (only traverse the package list once) and will be strictly limited to the local package catalog.

If you want to limit the output to packages that are currently installed, add the `db:Status-Abbrev` field and filter on that e.g.

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev}\t${binary:Package} - ${binary:Summary}\n' | 
  awk '/^ii/'
```

or

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev}\t${binary:Package} - ${binary:Summary}\n' | 
  awk -F'\t' '/^ii/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: I got 2 comments: 1) the first command sounded good but it gives description of all packages: it's not exactly what I'm looking for. 2) the second command looks amazingly fast, however I'm seeing packages which are not shown from `apt list --installed`: how come ?

Comment: For the first command, it would be better to have a `xargs -n1 apt-cache search ^{} \;`. How to feed the argument with "^" ?

Comment: @Soleil you can add `--names-only` to restrict the scope of the search to package names

Comment: Unfortunately, `--names-only` doesn't work/help.

Comment: `dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}: ${binary:Summary}\n'` gives packages I installed then removed. How can I clean them from appearing here ?

Comment: @Soleil please see updated answer

Comment: That's a great answer. The last command is perfect. Thanks also for providing the final xargs command with the `{}` :D.

Comment: Eventually, to finish the task, can you look at this last question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039169/how-to-alias-the-right-way-a-dpkg-query-command-with-pipe