# How to alias the right way a dpkg-query command (with pipe)?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, dpkg, alias

I'm adding this alias to `.bashrc` (in one line of course), but unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
alias lspkg="dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev}\t${binary:Package} - ${binary:Summary}\n'
| awk -F'\t' '/^ii/ {print $2}'"
```

Any idea why ? I tried to backslash the backslash or the single quote, without better results.

**Reference:**

[How to pipe installed packages to apt-cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039075/how-to-pipe-installed-packages-to-apt-cache)

Comment: Does it work as intended? I believe aliases don't take positional parameters. Just try `alias soleil="echo Hello $1 Ubuntu $2"; soleil Ask !`. It returns `Hello  Ubuntu Ask !`

Comment: The command with protected `\$` works perfectly, that's why I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `${}` and `$` are getting eaten by the shell due to the `"`, so the `$` need to be escaped.

```
alias lspkg="dpkg-query -W -f='\${db:Status-Abbrev}\t\${binary:Package} - \${binary:Summary}\n' | awk -F'\t' '/^ii/ {print \$2}'"
```

Generally, when debugging shell commands one can use `echo` to check things out, as in:

```
$ echo "dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev}\t${binary:Package} - ${binary:Summary}\n'
| awk -F'\t' '/^ii/ {print $2}'"
dpkg-query -W -f='\t - \n'
| awk -F'\t' '/^ii/ {print }'
$ _
```

Then, one can see what's missing by visual inspection.

Comment: Great method with `echo`.